# CollectionView cell Snapkit constraints fail when applying offset

Tags: swift, snapkit

I have the follwowing constraints applied to my Cell via SnapKit and they work fine.

```
    self.imageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
      make.leading.top.trailing.equalToSuperview()
      make.bottom.equalTo(self.nameLabel.snp.top)
      if let width = self.imageView.image?.size.width {
          make.height.equalTo(width)
      }
    }

    self.nameLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
      make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
      make.top.equalTo(self.imageView.snp.bottom)
      make.bottom.equalTo(self.priceLabel.snp.top)
    }

    self.priceLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
      make.top.equalTo(self.nameLabel.snp.bottom)
      make.leading.trailing.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }
```

but when i try to add space between the `imageView` and the `nameLabel` i get errors

```
    self.productImageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
      make.leading.top.trailing.equalToSuperview()
      make.bottom.equalTo(self.productNameLabel.snp.top).inset(-8) // change here
      if let width = self.productImageView.image?.size.width {
          make.height.equalTo(width)
      }
    }

    self.productNameLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
      make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
      make.top.equalTo(self.productImageView.snp.bottom).offset(8) // change here
      make.bottom.equalTo(self.productPriceLabel.snp.top)
    }

    self.productPriceLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
      make.top.equalTo(self.productNameLabel.snp.bottom)
      make.leading.trailing.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }
```

What i dont understand is if i move the minus in the constraints to the other 8 then the errors dissapear but the views are now overlapping. I feel im missing something basic but dont know what.

Here is what i am hoping for:

[image]

Comment: You don't need to duplicate contraint, i think remove this line every think will ok: "      make.bottom.equalTo(self.productNameLabel.snp.top).inset(-8) // change here"

Comment: Ive tried this, and get similar issues where using inset or offset works but brings the views closer together, when i use a negative number i get the constraint errors

Comment: what error, and what is your size of your cell, is the cell size automatic ?

Answer (score 1):

So this had nothing to do with the cell itself but the size of the collectionView containing the cells